# How to manage app resource for a UI library when the Application.Resource affects the look of the library control?

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, resources

I'm developing a UI library project. It contains set of pages that will be used in two different UWP app projects. The problem is that in one project, the developers uses a theme that modifies the appearance of the basic controls such as the font size of a textblock or TextBox, the margin of the ContentControls etc. In my library, I used pretty basic controls text box, combobox, date picker. It affects how the pages in the UI library that I'm working on looks. I want the pages in my library to look like a basic input form. How can I tell the UI library to not follow whatever theme the Application is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell the UI library to not follow whatever theme the Application is using?

You could add a 'Resource Dictionary' file in your UI library project. In the 'dictionary.xaml' file, you could define a basic style for the controls which is used in your UI library pages. Then, the controls will not be affected by the resource style in the main project.

For example, I add a 'generic.xaml' file in the UI library project and define a style for the button like the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ClassLibraryUI">
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}">
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a 'BlankPage1.xaml' in the UI library.

```
<Page
x:Class="ClassLibraryUI.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ClassLibraryUI"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Hello UWP"></Button>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

In the main project, I defined a style for the button in 'App.xaml':

```
<Application
x:Class="AppUI.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppUI">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

On the 'MainPage.xaml':

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Navigate" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <Frame x:Name="frame"></Frame>
</StackPanel>
```

In the 'MainPage.xaml.cs', I use `Frame` control to navigate to the 'BalnkPage1' in the UI library.

You would see the 'Navigate' button on the MainPage will use the style in 'Application.Resources', but the button on 'BlankPage1' will use the style in its own 'generic.xaml' file.

Comment: Does it mean that I will have to add the resource dictionary to every page in the library project?

Comment: @Lance In short, yes. You would have to add the resource dictionary to every page. But you could add just one page in your library project, and make other pages as UserControl. With this way, you just need to add the resource dictionary one time on this page, other UserControls will be hosted on this page by different conditions.